Mysql 8.0.35 - I cannot get rid of filesort caused by a JSON column
I spent days researching, trying solutions etc with no success, filesort is still happening
My whole table is only 300MB and the part I am selecting is 767 rows and around 30MB
My query using filesort is the following
select * 
from finance_trans_deposits 
where finance_trans_deposits.id_customer = 123 
    and finance_trans_deposits.id_customer is not null 
    and status = 2 
order by created_at desc;

And this is EXPLAIN output
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | partitions | type | possible_keys                  | key                | key_len | ref        | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | finance_trans_deposits | NULL      | ref  | idx_customer_status,id_customer | idx_customer_status | 9      | const,const |  767 |  100.00 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

The reason for this issue is 100% a single json column in my table, if I change "select *" to select "list of all columns excluding JSON column", it takes 0.01s (instead of 0.5s). Json data in each row is around 30kb, so all json data in whole select is around 20MB.
I tried adjusting sort_buffer_size to various values, I tried from 256MB up to 5GB (I have a lot of memory) but the issue remains
OPTIMIZER TRACE  shows the following
"filesort_summary": {
"memory_available": 2147483648,
"key_size": 9,
"row_size": 4294967295,
"max_rows_per_buffer": 0,
"num_rows_estimate": 767,
"num_rows_found": 767,
"num_initial_chunks_spilled_to_disk": 0,
"peak_memory_used": 28640470,
"sort_algorithm": "std::stable_sort",
"sort_mode": "<fixed_sort_key, packed_additional_fields>"
}

I am wondering what row_size is, it is 4GB but this table definitely has only 300MB,
memory used is only 28 MB, I believe this is the real size of the selected dataset (my calculation was only estimate), why is it not being sorted in memory? I am starting to think this is a mysql bug
CREATE TABLE `finance_trans_deposits` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `validation_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_customer` bigint NOT NULL,
  `session_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `amount_eur` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `payment_method_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `provider_pm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `provider_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `force_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `risk_score` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bonus_want` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payload` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `forwarded_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsw` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsw_eur` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsw_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `pre_notification_sent_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE finance_trans_deposits
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
ADD KEY id_customer_2 (id_customer,status,created_at);
I made a copy of my table to be able to alter it freely (its a production env). After copying I discovered the table has suddenly 470MB instead of 300 it had before (same number of rows, I verified).
I cleaned everything, I removed all indexes and created a new single index on these 3 columns
It has not changed anything in terms of query time (still 0.5s) however output of EXPLAIN has changed, now it shows
Backward index scan
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+---------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref        | rows | filtered | Extra              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | 2test | NULL      | ref  | id_customer_2 | id_customer_2 | 9      | const,const |  767 |  100.00 | Backward index scan |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+---------------------+

so you think filesort is gone? I am not convinced, because the query still takes 0.5s. When I drop the json column the same query takes 0.01s (just tested), why is JSON column causing this still, I do not believe it is the big amount of data in that column, like I said it is not more than 50kb per row, sometimes NULL
When I select on JSON column only (not SELECT *) its the same time 0.5
I am attaching below EXPLAIN ANALYZE, keep in mind this is after creating a new index on all 3 columns id_customer,status,created_at
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| -> Index lookup on finance_trans_deposits  using id_customer_2 (id_customer=123, status=2) (reverse)  (cost=844 rows=767) (actual time=0.157..7.37 rows=767 loops=1)
 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

it shows that the seelct took 7 miliseconds, but when I actually run the query it shows 767 rows in set (0.53 sec)
Output of SHOW CREATE TABLE
finance_trans_deposits | CREATE TABLE `finance_trans_deposits` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `validation_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_customer` bigint NOT NULL,
  `session_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `amount_eur` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `payment_method_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `provider_pm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `provider_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `force_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `risk_score` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bonus_want` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payload` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `forwarded_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsw` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsw_eur` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsw_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `pre_notification_sent_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `finance_trans_deposits_payment_method_id_foreign` (`payment_method_id`),
  KEY `id_customer` (`id_customer`),
  KEY `id_customer_2` (`id_customer`,`status`,`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `finance_trans_deposits_payment_method_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`payment_method_id`) REFERENCES `finance_payment_methods` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27103 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

First time using profiler, I hope I used it correctly. I did SET profiling=1, then I run the query, and SHOW PROFILE. Here is output
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000272 |
| Executing hook on transaction  | 0.000018 |
| starting                       | 0.000022 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000017 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000134 |
| init                           | 0.000021 |
| System lock                    | 0.000027 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000048 |
| statistics                     | 0.000213 |
| preparing                      | 0.000069 |
| executing                      | 0.554983 |
| end                            | 0.000014 |
| query end                      | 0.000003 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000006 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000013 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000011 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000038 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000009 |
+--------------------------------+----------+

Interestingly it shows executing took 0.55s

Please add the indexes to your CREATE TABLE output.

I agree it sounds like a bug. What happens if you do SELECT payload FROM ..., i.e. select only the JSON column?

An index on (id_customer, status, created_at) (three columns in that order) should do it. Thank you for including your table definition, but it isn't complete. The EXPLAIN you show names two indexes that are at least part of this table, but your CREATE TABLE doesn't show them.

wow 15 minutes and already 3 responses, thank you guys I really appreciate it, give me 5 minutes and I will post a response after I try your solutions

I updated the original post above with a new data at the bottom


Could you show an explain analyze for your queries, and make it very clear what your indexes are. 2) Try analyzing the table to ensure the query planner has up to date stats. 3) How many rows are returned by the query, and how many rows are in the table?


@Schwern, I updated original post above with output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE - that is using a new index I created on all 3 columns id_customer,status,created_at. I did run OPTIMIZE earlier, it does not make any difference. The whole table has 27k rows and 767 are returned.

Thanks, that's helpful and eliminates some of the obvious problems. It looks like your query is executing in 7ms but retrieval is taking 500ms. 30k per row is a lot. If the server is remote, there's also network overhead; 500ms sounds reasonable for 20 MB. That would explain why its so much faster without selecting the JSON. Try using the profiler. You also might want to ask this on DBA.SE.

You could also test the theory about network overhead by running the query from a client on the database server (or at least adjacent to the database server on the same local network). If you eliminate the slow network in between client and server, that will give you a measurement to either confirm or rule out network speed as the culprit.

Consider posting TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE 'finance_trans_deposits';  and the true current index definitions will be in the output, please.  Welcome to SO.

.. and finance_trans_deposits.id_customer is not null .. condition is obviously excess and must be removed.

@Akina It is unnecessary, but removing it won't have an affect on the query plan.

@Schwern removing it won't have an affect on the query plan Of course, because the optimizer have removed this condition due to NOT NULL column definition.

I run these queries manually, directly on the server console, there is no network overhead, I will update original post with SHOW CREATE TABLE in a moment

I added output of SHOW CREATE TABLE. I am definitely starting to think that it takes so much time to read these JSON values, I googled and it says that returning such a big JSON data is expensive

add show profile information

@ratatata  When you post profiler output, please POST the query you RAN so we know what caused these resources to be used.  There have been too many things documented without the EXACT query used to get results.  They have to be paired to be meaningful when someone looks at your Question 30 days from now.

When you run a query that includes the payload column, have you considered SELECTING payload(100),...... to avoid handling up to 30K of string data rather than just the first 100 characters?

All of this information is always for the same query listed at the beginning of my original post

@ratatata The first query listed does not include the column payload so I am not sure why you wandered off in the direction of payload, your only JSON column. Welcome to SO.
